Unable to run Flask application after adding __init__.py to root folder
New to python and Flask development. I have an application algo.trader located at ~/algo.trader. I am trying to use the Application Factory pattern to initialize the app using a create_app() function within __init__.py. I am running the flask application like so:
FLASK_APP=app.py flask run --port=8000 --debug

Everything is ok till I add even an empty __init__.py. The moment I do that and run the application, I get the error:
Error: Could not import 'algo.trader.app'.  

__init__.py is placed in the root directory along with app.py.
My questions:

I think the presence of an __init__.py file might be making Pycharm feel like this is a package?
How does one solve for this? I have been googling but not gotten very far.


First of all you should share your app.py file. Additionally why do you want to use application factory pattern, why do you feel the need to add an __init__.py and ultimately what are you trying to achieve?
